# Shapely point object and Geopandas data frame yield empty output

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

I have a Geopandas df 'districts' of all districts in Paris and a shapley point object 'eiffel_tower' of the Eiffel Tower.
When I execute

```
mask=districts.contains(eiffel_tower)
districts[mask]
```

Thanks. I tried districts.geometry.contains(eiffel_tower); but no luck. The 'eiffel_tower'  and districts are as below:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
eiffel_tower = Point(255422.6, 6250868.9)
      
districts=geopandas.read_file('Paris/paris_districts_utm.geojson')
```

> districts.head(2) shows:
> id    district_name   population geometry
> 0    1   St-Germain-l'Auxerrois  1672    POLYGON ((451922.133
> 5411438.484,...
> 1    2   Halles                 8984  POLYGON ((452278.419 5412160.893,...

I get an empty output. What could be wrong?

TIA
Sheri

Comment: What is the data type of `district`? I ask because only a GeoSeries has the function `contains()`. Elsewise your code looks good and I think you need to check your data. Is some district missing? Is there a typo in the coordinates? Can you find the correct district in your data by hand?

Comment: Thanks. district is of data type  geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

Comment: It's hard to guess, how your columns are names, but if you have for example `geometry` in it, when try `districts.geometry.contains(eiffel_tower)`. It this doesn't solve your problem, please extend your example, show how your GeoDataFrame and your Point eiffel_tower are defiend.

Comment: Thanks. I tried districts.geometry.contains(eiffel_tower); but no luck. The 'eiffel_tower'  and districts are as below:

from shapely.geometry import Point
eiffel_tower = Point(255422.6, 6250868.9)

districts=geopandas.read_file('Paris/paris_districts_utm.geojson')

districts.head(2) shows:

id district_name population               geometry
0 1 St-Germain-l'Auxerrois 1672 POLYGON ((451922.133 5411438.484, ...
1 2 Halles                          8984  POLYGON ((452278.419 5412160.893,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your geolocation for the Eiffel Tower seems not to match the districts. The first value is much smaller (255422) then the one of the dirstricts (451922, ...).

To be sure about it, perform `district.geometry.bounds`, which will return `minx`, `miny`, `maxx` and `maxy`, then you can check by hand and probably you will see, that the location of the Eiffel Tower is not in this area.

**Guessing:**
My first thought was, that you have a typo in `eiffel_tower = Point(255422.6, 6250868.9)` and it should be `eiffel_tower = Point(455422.6, 6250868.9)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are correct. I have just used the UTM value of the Eiffel Tower
Point(448265.91, 5411920.65) and got the correct result. Thanks again for your support.